# Three.js engrave a mesh

Tags: three.js

I want to Real-time engrave ring service. So, I want how to engraving ring in `Three.js`.

I bring a ring in a gltf file.Then I tried ThreeCSG.js and the error is `not convex!`

This is the example code.

```
var ring, temp;

THREE.DRACOLoader.setDecoderPath('');
THREE.DRACOLoader.setDecoderConfig({type:'js'});

var loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();
loader.setDRACOLoader(new THREE.DRACOLoader());
loader.load('files/test.gltf', function(gltf){
    gltf.scene.traverse(function(child)){
        if(child.name === 'ring'){
            child.material = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
                color : 0xffffff
            });
            ring = THREE.CSG.fromMesh(child);
            temp = child;
        }
    }
    scene.add(gltf.scene);
})

function engrave(text){
    var fLoader = new THREE.FontLoader();
    fLoader.load('font.json', function (font){
        var fGeometry = new THREE.TextGeometry(text, {
            ...
        });

        var fMaterial = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
            ...
        });

        var font = new THREE.Mesh(fGeometry, fMaterial);

        var csg = THREE.CSG.fromMesh(font);

        var result = mesh.subtract(csg);

        temp.visible = false;
        scene.add(THREE.CSG.toMesh(result, fMaterial);
    });
}
```

I wish somebody answer my question.

Comment: Maybe makes sense to use a displacement map?

Comment: @prisoner849 I've been thinking about that, But the uv map of the gltf files is irregular.

Comment: Which CSG library are you using? As far as I know there shouldn't be a convexity requirement..

Comment: @manthrax I've solved the error, but there's another one. I remember that it was probably an error that was out of max hip size.

Answer (score 1):

The most commonly available CSG library for THREE has a few issues that make it unusable for some cases.

I have ported my own version of a CSG library that has less of these issues.. perhaps you'd like to try this library instead?

https://github.com/manthrax/THREE-CSGMesh